# expression engine / truncation - remove anything inside a <pre> tag

Tags: php, expressionengine, truncate, pre, truncation

I'm using an expression engine field to post code samples using a `<pre>` element and `[code]` markup, but I'm also using this field as an excerpt. In the excerpt, I want to remove anything inside these pre elements (or stop, somehow, once it reaches the `<pre>` element. Anyone know how to do this? Here's my excerpt code:

```
<p class="excerpt">{exp:trunchtml chars="300"}{code_content}{/exp:trunchtml}</p>
```

and here's a sample entry containing code:

```
</p>Blah blah blah Lorem Ipsum</p> <pre>[code]camera.position.set(0,20,35); [/code]</pre>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a pretty specific need, no existing plugin I know of will do that. Your two options are:

Create a dedicated excerpt field (really the best in terms of crafting better excerpts and keeping your data structured).

Or, [write your own plugin](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/development/plugins.html) (really not very difficult) which will take the contents you pass it, then
    perform some `preg_replace()` on it to eliminate your `<pre>`
    elements and all their contents, returning the cleaned result.

So it would look something like this:

```
<p class="excerpt">
    {exp:trunchtml chars="300"}
        {exp:my_plugin:replace_pre}{code_content}{/exp:my_plugin:replace_pre}
    {/exp:trunchtml}
</p>
```

This bit of PHP would do the magic for you inside your plugin:

```
$content = $this->EE->TMPL->tagdata;
preg_replace('/<pre[^>]*>.*?<\/pre>/i', '', $content);
return $content;
```